# When quartz-redis-jobstore 1.2.0 will be released?

Tags: redis, quartz-scheduler, job-scheduling

Does anybody know when **quartz-redis-jobstore** version **1.2.0** will be released.
I needs it for app using jedis 3.3.0 version. On the github https://github.com/jlinn/quartz-redis-jobstore has been available for a year, but it has not been on maven central still.

Thanks

Comment: Seems like the project has been abandoned. I've locally forked and re-compiled it, you can do the same (and use the built jar as local dependency),  can share the code with you if desired.

Comment: Thank you very much, I did it the same way.